Failing to build Lua for EFI environment (EDK2)
I am trying to build Lua for EDK2 but it fails with the following error.
/home/dave/dev/edk2libc/edk2-libc/AppPkg/Applications/Lua/src/ldo.c: In function ‘luaD_throw’:
/home/dave/dev/edk2libc/edk2-libc/AppPkg/Applications/Lua/src/ldo.c:122:1: error: ‘noreturn’ function does return [-Werror]
  122 | }
      | ^

In the answers to the following post Lua.efi package for running lua in EFI environment; 'unixsmurf' mentions a patch to avoid build errors but the link is broken, so perhaps I need that patch, anyone know where it may be?
I am able to build the 'Hello' sample application without issue so my build environment seems ok.

I assume he meant this patch.
You need to add the NORETURN attribute to

LongJump: MdePkg/Include/Library/BaseLib.h
InternalLongJump: MdePkg/Library/BaseLib/BaseLibInternals.h

In addition to the changes in the patch, you also need to add it to:

longjmp: StdLib/Include/setjmp.h


Thank you for patch, I have tried it but seems to fail with same error. The only way I can get it to build is to force the definition of l_noret to void in llimits.h. Any ideas?

I updated my answer, you also need to mark longjmp in the stdlib package with the noreturn attribute.

Thank you that fixed it, much appreciated.
